# how to adjust matrix after convolution MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, convolution

Assume that I have greyscale image I that have 300 x 300

and I have matrix matrix M 3 x 3

after the convolution

```
Ans = conv2(I,M);
```

ans will be matrix 304 x 304 => convolute will extend the matrix

If I want the answer to be a matrix like I
Can I force it like

```
Ans = Ans(1+2:304-2;1+2:304-2);
```

Comment: `ans` would actually be a matrix of size 302 x 302

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the options in `conv2`

```
Ans = conv2(I,M,'same');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conv2(Image, Kernel, 'same')`:

```
>> load clown % X = image of a clown
>> size(X)

ans =

   200   320

>> I = ones(10, 10);
>> size(conv2(X, I))

ans =

    209   329

>> size(conv2(X,I,'same'))

ans =

    200   320
```